# Function does not exist in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers, procedure

I have this Postgres code

```
CREATE PROCEDURE adjust_available(patientBed UUID)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    UPDATE bed
    SET available = false
    WHERE bed.id = patientBed;
$$;

CREATE TRIGGER adjust_available
    AFTER UPDATE OF bed ON patient
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE adjust_available(bed);
```

However when you run this query. It says the function does not exist. However, you create it above?

The full error:

> ERROR:  function adjust_available() does not exist
> SQL state: 42883

Comment: Best guess is the procedure is not in your `search_path`. What does `show search_path ;` return?

Comment: "$user", public

Comment: What does `\df public.adjust_available` show?  Also add to your question the actual entire error message.

Comment: Where do i need to type that command?

Comment: I was not paying attention. You created a `PROCEDURE`.  Contrary to what `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` says it needs to be a function. `EXECUTE PROCEDURE` is deprecated  and the proper usage is `EXECUTE FUNCTION`. For more information see [CREATE TRIGGER](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html).

Comment: Also the trigger function needs to have a return type of  `trigger`

Answer (score 1):

Though the [`CREATE TRIGGER`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html) statement allows a `PROCEDURE` keyword for the `EXECUTE` clause, it doesn't actually allow procedures to be executed. From the documentation:

> In the syntax of CREATE TRIGGER, the keywords FUNCTION and PROCEDURE are equivalent, but the referenced function must in any case be a function, not a procedure. The use of the keyword PROCEDURE here is historical and deprecated.

Instead, you must use a [trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html), which must not declare arguments (though arguments can be accessed as strings via the special `TG_ARGV[]` array variable) and must have a return type of `trigger` or, for [event triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/event-triggers.html), `event_trigger`. Speaking generally & simplistically, functions for row-level `BEFORE` and `INSTEAD OF` triggers should return `NULL` to cancel the rest of the operation and `NEW` to continue. The return value is ignored by `AFTER` and statement-level `BEFORE` triggers; it may as well be `NULL`.

Based on the question sample code (untested):

```
CREATE FUNCTION adjust_available()
  RETURNS trigger
  LANGUAGE plpgsql
  AS $$
  BEGIN
    UPDATE bed
      SET available = false
      WHERE bed.id = TG_ARGV[0]::UUID;
    RETURN NULL; -- return value for AFTER trigger is ignored
  END
  $$;
```

(Transferred from the question comments.)